# База данных хранящая в себе файлы.

Tags: c#, .net, база-данных

Всем привет. Есть такой вопрос. Какую базу данных можно использовать в C# (то есть подключить ее к C#), которая хранит в себе файлы, а не адрес (путь) к файлу. На конкретном примере мне надо в моем приложении добавлять аудио файлы и открывать их из базы, которая хранит в себе тот файл. Надеюсь вопрос изъясни понятно. Всем спасибо ;)

Comment: Почему вы хотите хранить файлы в базе данных? Базы данных для этого не предназначены по определению. Принято именно хранить ссылку в базе, а файл отдельно на диске.

Comment: @SergeyRufanov согласен, но у меня такое задание, которое не обсуждается, если я хочу иметь выше оценку :)

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете использовать любую базу данных для этой цели. Они одинаково не предназначены для хранения файлов - и нет разницы, в какой СУБД файлы хранить.

Comment: Ну не совсем так, на самом деле - некоторые всё таки предназначенны для этого.

Comment: Практически любая база, которую ты сможешь использовать из C#, умеет хранить файлы (в виде BLOB - бинарных блоков данных). Включая MS SQL, Firebird, MySql, Sqlite.

Comment: @Nikolay, однако когда требуется в BLOB-ах хранить данных больше чем пара-тройка-сотня килобайт - начинаются проблемы... )) Для средних и крупных файлов они не подходят.

Comment: Ну тут же похоже речь о сдаче лабы, а не о высоконагруженной системе для хранения HD-RIP. Базы уже десятки лет как хранят файлы подобным образом, хотя подобная архитектура и не является верхом совершенства. В общем я бы сказал топикстартеру, что можно использовать любую базу, лучше ту, с которой он умеет работать.

Comment: @Nikolay - если вы хотели ответить на вопрос - надо было запостить это как ответ, а не как комментарий к чужому ответу (тем более что суть ответа - та же, что у вашего комментария)

Answer (score 3):

Можете использовать например [FileStream-хранилище](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234(v=sql.105).aspx) SQL Server. Оно предназначенно именно для хранения средних и больших файлов.

Внутри оно устроенно так-же, как вы описали - в самой базе хранятся ссылки, а файлы отдельно. Однако управляет файлами SQL-server, и от пользователя весь механизм скрыт и абстрактен - в SQL оно представляется как простые колонки типа varbinary(max) + уникальный uuid.

Answer (score 0):

Решением данного вопроса для себя я нашел такое:

Простая MySql БД, но поле, которое должно хранить (любой файл) должно быть типа "BLOB". 
Отдельное спасибо @Nikolay !
И всем, кто принял участие в помощи юному падавану ;)